# Apple binary plist and/or keyed archive file format documentation?

Tags: macos, ios, plist, file-format

Are Apple's binary [plist format](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) and/or the related [keyed archive](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Concepts/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-133256-BAJDGHID) format actually documented anywhere?

I know that there is Apple [open source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/darwinsource/10.5.5/CF-476.15/CFBinaryPList.c) for binary plist parsing out there, which is a good start, but reverse-engineering the format and its revisions from that is less than ideal. Is there any actual explicit documentation on this format?

Thanks.

Comment: That open source code contains a layout description of the format in comments. Together with the DTD ( http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd ), is that not enough specification? BTW, you can use plutil to do the conversion for you: plutil -convert xml1 -o - foo.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. They're formats private to Apple. As jackrabbit commented above, you should convert it to an XML plist and use any of the XML parsers available if you want interoperability.